# Which scope is required to send emails through gmail oauth in nodemailer?

Tags: oauth, scope, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I have setup the authentication of google accounts and I'm able to get the access and refresh token of users but when I set the scope to only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send it doesn't work but when I set the authentication scope to https://mail.google.com/ then it works without problem. What is going on here? Why can't I just use the send scope for sending emails via nodemailer? Here is my code:-

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        clientId: 'my_client_id',
        clientSecret: 'my_client_secret'
    }
});

transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'user@gmail.com',
    to: 'target@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Message',
    text: 'Hi there',
    auth: {
        user: 'user@gmail.com',
        refreshToken: 'user_refresh_token',
        accessToken: 'user_access_token'
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a note in the Nodemailer documentation saying the scope has to be 'https://mail.google.com/': https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#troubleshooting

And it is actually specified by Google here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol

Answer (score 0):

As the answer by @bfredo123 suggests, nodemailer only works with the https://mail.google.com scope (https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#troubleshooting).

It does not work with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send scope. Since the https://mail.google.com scope gives permission to delete all emails in the inbox, nodemailer may not work for your application.

Solution: I banged my head at this problem for a week. So I hope this helps someone.

Use the gmail API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) or gmail.users.messages.send instead of nodemailer to send emails. Since the API is offered directly by google, it works with the gmail.send scope. Here is some sample code:

```
import { google } from "googleapis";
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"
);


function makeBody(to, from, subject, message) {
  var str = [
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\n',
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
    "to: ",
    to,
    "\n",
    "from: ",
    from,
    "\n",
    "subject: ",
    subject,
    "\n\n",
    message,
  ].join("");

  var encodedMail = new Buffer(str)
    .toString("base64")
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_");
  return encodedMail;
}

export const sendEmail = async () => {
    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: oauth2Client });
    let raw = makeBody(
      "receiver@gmail.com",
      "sender@gmail.com",
      "my subject",
      "my body"
    );
    const response = await gmail.users.messages.send({
      userId: emailOptions.from,
      resource: { raw },
    });
    console.log("this is the response", response); 
}
```